# Different manifest files to same web project office add-in

Tags: ms-office, office365, add-in, office-js, office-addins

I have recently published an Outlook Add-in (simple one task pane firing an API call with inserting text received back).

Now I am interested in developing the same for the other Office products (Word, Excel , etc).

I was wondering if it is possible to have, let's say, a Word manifest, Excel manifest and Outlook manifest all pointing to the same web project but different folders in the project.

[image: An example folder structure for a solution with Excel, Outlook, and Word manifests. Hand drawn arrows point from the manifests to different folders in the same web project.]

Comment: Thanks for the edit @BSMP.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I somehow missed that the image got broken! It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rick-kirkham I have managed to create multiple manifest files with one web project holding the different folders to which the manifests point. I currently have an Outlook, Word and Excel add-in using the same web project.

One thing I had to do is remove the reference in the manifest file project that points to the web folder.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of having an add-in that works on multiple Office host applications is to have multiple `<host>` sections in a single manifest (one host for each Office application). That said, I think it is possible in principle to have separate manifest files (which means, in effect, separate add-ins) for each host application. The critical thing is to make sure that the various URL values in each manifest point to the appropriate place for that add-in. If you haven't already, be sure you are familiar with the [documentation about the manifest XML](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/add-in-manifests).

Comment: I have tried using different manifest files pointing to the same web directory. I am using VS 2015 and it creates 2 projects within the solution - a manifest project and a web one. I would point all the details to the same web project as shown in the picture and then delete the web directory for the manifest so that I have multiple manifests pointing to the same web directory - I could not figure out why it would not work - but will try using different hosts in the same manifest.